# Why am I getting an uncontrolled to controlled error?

Tags: reactjs

Whenever I input the same I get `Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled.` Changing the number input doesn't bring up this warning, and I have numerous other inputs set up the same way with no warning, im confused...

```
const [malt, setMalt] = useState([{ name: "", grams: 0 }]);

.....

 <Input
              value={malt.name}
              onChange={(e) => setMalt({ ...malt, name: e.target.value })}
              placeholder="Malt"
            />

            <NumberInput>
              <InputGroup>
                <NumberInputField
                  value={malt.grams}
                  onChange={(e) => setMalt({ ...malt, grams: e.target.value })}
                  placeholder="Grams"
                />
                <InputRightAddon children="g" />
              </InputGroup>
            </NumberInput>
```

Comment: You start with an array `useState([{ name: "", grams: 0 }])`, array doesn't have names, so it is undefined, which means uncontrolled, then you suddenly add a name and it becomes controlled. Is `malt` supposed to be an object or an array?

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @Nadia Chibrikova  I fixed it by removing the square brackets and making it an object `const [malt, setMalt] = useState({ name: "", grams: 0 });`